# I want to find top 10 customers in R in which :

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I need create a user define function in which the user is able to specify the product(Gold/Silver/Platinum) and time(yearly or monthly) and Do the aggregation for both yearly and monthly such that when user specify month, the monthly data aggregated while identifying top 10 customers from each city.

Till now what i tried is not executing and can't understand what to do further

What I did :

```
udf <- function(product,time_period){
  if(product="gold" & time_period="monthly")
    print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,mnth)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
  else if(product="gold" & time_period="yearly")
  print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,year)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
  else if(product="silver" & time_period="monthly")
  print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,mnth)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
  else if(product="silver" & time_period="yearly")
  print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,year)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
  else if(product="platinum" & time_period="monthly")
  print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,mnth)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
  else
  print(dataset%>%group_by(product="Gold",City,Customer,year)%>%summarise(repayment=sum(Amount))%>%top_n(10))
  
}
```

Dataset :

```
structure(list(No = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Customer = c("A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", 
"A4", "A4", "A4"), Age = c(76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
71, 71, 71, 71, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 47, 
47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47), City = c("BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", 
"BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", 
"BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", 
"BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", "BANGALORE", 
"BANGALORE", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", 
"CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", "CALCUTTA", 
"CALCUTTA", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", 
"COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "COCHIN", "BOMBAY", 
"BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", "BOMBAY", 
"BOMBAY", "BOMBAY"), Product = c("Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", 
"Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", 
"Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Gold", "Silver", "Silver", 
"Silver", "Silver", "Silver", "Silver", "Silver", "Silver", "Silver", 
"Silver", "Silver", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", 
"Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", 
"Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", 
"Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Platinum"), 
    Limit = c(500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 
    500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 
    500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 500000L, 100000L, 100000L, 
    100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 
    100000L, 100000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 
    10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10001L, 10001L, 
    10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L, 10001L
    ), Company = c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
    "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
    "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
    "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", 
    "C3", "C3", "C3", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C4", 
    "C4", "C4", "C4"), Segment = c("Self Employed", "Self Employed", 
    "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", 
    "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", 
    "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", 
    "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", "Self Employed", 
    "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", 
    "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", 
    "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_MNC", "Salaried_Pvt", 
    "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", 
    "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", 
    "Salaried_Pvt", "Salaried_Pvt", "Govt", "Govt", "Govt", "Govt", 
    "Govt", "Govt", "Govt", "Govt", "Govt", "Govt"), SL.No. = c(NA, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 103L, 117L, 131L, 145L, 159L, 173L, 
    187L, 201L, 215L, 229L, 243L, 104L, 118L, 132L, 146L, 160L, 
    174L, 188L, 202L, 216L, 230L, 244L, 105L, 119L, 133L, 147L, 
    161L, 175L, 189L, 203L, 217L, 231L, 245L, 106L, 120L, 134L, 
    148L, 162L, 176L, 190L, 204L, 218L, 232L), Month = structure(c(12429, 
    12420, 12432, 12442, 12800, 12837, 12815, 12429, 12453, 13257, 
    13109, 13473, 12967, 13394, 12837, 13239, 12432, 12830, 12420, 
    12842, 12514, 12745, 13109, 12998, 13424, 12817, 13240, 12442, 
    12837, 12432, 12830, 12900, 12927, 12745, 13029, 13455, 13183, 
    13241, 12429, 12817, 12442, 12837, 12543, 12928, 12927, 13059, 
    13485, 13232, 13242, 12420), class = "Date"), Amount = c(495414.75, 
    1e+05, 10000, 10001, 10002, 1e+05, 14473.41, 10000, 117964.43, 
    79849.19, 402099.78, 100003, 100001, 100003, 96670.7, 429099.97, 
    453027.64, 187398.64, 10001, 1e+05, 148038.67, 1e+05, 10274, 
    100002, 298423.86, 1e+05, 339899.24, 298200.38, 132970.25, 
    10002, 10000, 10002, 10000, 233364.46, 100003, 233945.84, 
    10000, 79705.12, 327273.46, 104406.96, 1e+05, 10001, 1e+05, 
    10001, 358341.19, 373214.8, 277825.13, 10001, 1e+05, 15557.49
    ), year = c(2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2004, 
    2004, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2004, 2005, 
    2004, 2005, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2004, 
    2005, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
    2004, 2005, 2004, 2005, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 
    2006, 2004), mnth = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 11, 11, 
    7, 9, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 11, 11, 8, 10, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 4, 5, 11, 9, 11, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 10, 12, 3, 
    4, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all the single `=` to double `==` to test for equality rather than assigning a value.

```
udf <- function(product, time_period) {
    if (product == "gold" & time_period == "monthly")
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, mnth) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
    else if (product == "gold" & time_period == "yearly")
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, year) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
    else if (product == "silver" & time_period == "monthly")
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, mnth) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
    else if (product == "silver" & time_period == "yearly")
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, year) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
    else if (product == "platinum" & time_period == "monthly")
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, mnth) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
    else
            print(dataset %>% group_by(product = "Gold", City, Customer, year) %>% summarise(repayment = sum(Amount)) %>% top_n(10))
}
```